# Grab file from Desktop in Django Shell

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, shell, django-shell

I have an app named cars inside my Django project that has a utils.py file that contains various utility methods used by the application.  One of them (grab_new_models) is used to process a CSV file that's normally picked up via a periodic tasks that fetches the file from a remote location. The method itself is passed the CSV file itself normally so that the method looks like

```
def grab_new_models(csv_file):
```

Right now I'm trying to update the code with some new functionality and having issues testing it locally.  Using the Django shell, I can't figure out how to pass the file into the method to test it.  I have a copy of the csv file on my Desktop.  How do I call this method from the Django shell and pass it my local csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are on the Django shell, which is python shell with some extra imports.
You can just import your util and call your function. Below I provide a simple example, which reads a simple file from my desktop and prints it:

Method:

```
def grab_new_models(csv_file):
    with open(csv_file) as f1:
        a = f1.read()
        print(a)
```

Execution:

```
grab_new_models(r'C:\Users\L3\Desktop\learn_note.txt')
```